# Como verificar se um valor existe num array multidimensional?

Tags: php

Eu tenho os seguintes dados vindo de um banco:

```
    array(2) {
  [0]=>
  object(stdClass)#28 (6) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(1) "5"
    ["user"]=>
    string(2) "26"
    ["created_date"]=>
    string(19) "2017-09-29 13:53:38"
    ["first_name"]=>
    string(8) "Gabriela"
    ["last_name"]=>
    string(5) "Silva"
    ["comment"]=>
    string(39) "esse é o comentario para o eeo"
  }
  [1]=>
  object(stdClass)#29 (6) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["user"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["created_date"]=>
    string(19) "2017-09-29 00:00:00"
    ["first_name"]=>
    string(8) "Vinicius"
    ["last_name"]=>
    string(6) "Aquino"
    ["comment"]=>
    string(13) "helloooooooo!"
  }
}
```

Como posso verificar se o **"user" 26** existe nessa array?

Comment: Pode usar um `forech` ou alguma função de `array_`

Comment: Eu pensei em usar foreach, mas gostaria de saber se existe outra opção, como você citou uma função de array, testei a in_array e não deu muito certo

Comment: Se existe o valor o que vai fazer com ele?

Comment: Ocultar um formulário.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Se você tem certeza de quantas dimensões são, no caso ali, aparentemente de um loop:

```
foreach($array as $row){
   if($row['user'] == '26'){
      return true;
   }
}
```

Você também pode usar:

```
foreach($array as $row){
   if (in_array('26', $array)) {
      return true;
   }
}
```

Você não consegue usar in_array direto na array justamente pelo dado estar em outra dimensão, vi ali que queria uma solução sem um loop, da pra 'gambiarrar', não é exatamente uma gambiarra mas:

Separe a coluna, junte, e agora sim verifique se existe:

```
$users_cods = array_column($array, 'user');

if(in_array('26',$users_cods)){
    return true;
}
```

Tem dezenas de formas de fazer isso, mas essas são as que eu utilizo.

Comment: Obrigado, melhor usar a primeira opção com loop achei mais simples.

Comment: AnthraxisBR, você se atentou ao fato que o *array* da pergunta possui objetos? Você acessou como se fosse um *array* associativo. Isso funciona? Pelo o que testei aqui (https://3v4l.org/5Tjkl), parece que não, ou me passou algum detalhe despercebido?

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss esse objeto do var dump é o objeto da classe não da array, a hora que passar pra uma variável ele se torna acessível, até porque se ele não passar ele não acessa os dados

Answer (score 2):

A resposta do @AnthraxisBR já responde, deixarei mais uma opção:

```
$needle = "26";
array_map(function($array) use ($needle) { return $array['user'] === $needle;}, $array);
```

Answer (score 2):

Outra sugestão que costumo utilizar em meus projetos. Segue minha contribuição.

```
<?php

$array = array(
    "user1" => array(
        "user" => "20",
        "dados" => array(),
    ),
    "user2" => array(
        "user" => "22",
        "dados" => array(),
    ),
);

$id = "20";
$coluna = "user";

echo $key = array_search(
    $id,
    array_filter(
        array_combine(
            array_keys($array),
            array_column(
                $array, $coluna
            )
        )
    )
); // user1

$key = array_search(
    '50', // Gerar error
    array_filter(
        array_combine(
            array_keys($array),
            array_column(
                $array, $coluna
            )
        )
    )
); // bool(false)
```